# Deleting row on sql database with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, pdo

I want to delete a row from my html page
I am using this function

```
function delete_row(no)
    {

        var row=document.getElementById("frm"+no).value;
        var data= {};
        data.row = row;


        $.ajax({
          url: 'delete_formation.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: data,

          success: function(output){
            //alert(output);
          }
        });
        document.getElementById("row"+no+"").outerHTML="";

    }
```

My delete_formation.php contains a php script to delete that row in my sql database :

```
<?php 

    /* Connexion à une base MySQL avec l'invocation de pilote */
    $pdo = 'mysql:dbname=TDW;host=127.0.0.1';
    $user = 'root';
    $password = '00000000';

    try {
        $pdo = new PDO($pdo, $user, $password);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connexion échouée : ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

$d=$_POST['row'];




try {
    // sql to delete a record
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM Types_formation WHERE type_id="'.$d.'"';
    echo $sql ;

    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $pdo->exec($sql);
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }?>
```

This is not working, and it seems that my js script is not getting that text where id="frm1" (for exemple)

Comment: This is a good time to start debugging.  Start in the browser.  Are there any errors on the browser's development console?  If you use the browser's debugger, is your `delete_row` function ever called?  Step through the code as it executes, are there any errors?  Does each variable contain the value you expect?  Is the AJAX call made to the server?  In the network tab of the debugging tools, what is the server's response?  You have a *ton* of information available to you other than "it doesn't work".  What does that information say?

Comment: everything seems to work fine ! the problem is that i can't get the text where id="frm1" id="frm2" ...

Comment: What does that even mean?  Please clarify the problem.  What "text"?  Where are you trying to "get" it?  When you debug, what *specific line of code* is producing an unexpected result?  What was the result?  What result were you expecting?  Why?  "Everything seems to work fine" isn't a problem anybody can solve.

Comment: I solved the problem .. i should have used innerText and not value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `var row=document.getElementById("frm"+no).innerText;`
instead of `var row=document.getElementById("frm"+no).value;` will solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pass value in ajax data variable and you get data $_post['row'] but you need $_post['data']['row'].

If this is not work than I will give full example.